# Unable to serve static file using cloud front with the origin server as ec2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a web application running on centos ec2 instance behind Nginx reverse proxy with SSL certification (Let's Encrypt).

I have a javascript file located at the URL for example `https://example.com/static/src/js/allEnd.js`
I used CloudFront to delivered the static file with the origin server as the HTTP ec2 instance (not using the s3 bucket.)
My origin server is mapped with the domain name `https://example.com` I have the following configuration I have made so far:
1. www.example.com is redirected to example.com in Nginx
2. The CloudFront URL is an alias with my custom domain ie cdn.example.com
3. SSL for example.com is done on Nginx whereas SSL for cdn,example.com is done on AWS.

What I have understood so far is the first time the CloudFront will serve the static content by getting the file from my ec2 server and then the next time it will serve from CloudFront but every time the CloudFront redirect to the origin server to get the static file which CloudFront is not serving in my case.

Here is the header for both the origin server and CloudFront server.

```
1. Origin server (https://example.com)
get https://example.com/static/src/js/allEnd.js
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx/1.12.2
date: Sun, 12 May 2019 12:27:50 GMT
content-type: application/javascript
content-length: 168435
etag: "wzsdm-1557567525-168435-283837276"
cache-control: max-age=604800, public
expires: Sun, 19 May 2019 12:27:50 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000

2. CloudFront with origin as https://example.com (https://cdn.example.com)
get https://cdn.example.com/static/src/js/allEnd.js
HTTP/2 301
content-type: text/html
content-length: 185
location: https://example.com/static/src/js/allEnd.js
server: nginx/1.12.2
date: Sun, 12 May 2019 09:17:40 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000
age: 17
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
via: 1.1 76d9b50884e58e2463b175e34e790838.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: HBbfJXbFgKQz4eYlQSpLPQAk8pxZRKuGsb6YjFu8-AJL0JwPfs8FZw==
```

As you can see the response header that the cdn.example.com (CloudFront) redirect to the origin (example.com).
Also, I am confused with the `content-type:text/html` which should be `content-type: application/javascript`

What are the possibilities that I may have misconfigured?

If anything more you want to know, Please feel free to ask. Thanks.

P.S: I am new to the Nginx and AWS configuration and most importantly cache control.

Comment: Try what Sqlbot mentioned but don't forget to clear the cache after you have made the changes, CloudFront caches 3xx response.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to examine the **origin server** configuration and log files to understand why this happened.

Check the origin server logs and you will find that the origin server originally generated that 301 redirect response  -- not CloudFront.

Notice that the response headers *from CloudFront* include `server: nginx/1.12.2`.  CloudFront did not add this.

The Content-Type is set as it is, because your origin server also returned HTML saying something like "object has moved" or "you are being redirected."  Modern browsers typically don't display that message, they just follow the redirect.

In any event, if the origin server returns a redirect, CloudFront does not *follow* the redirect returned by the origin server -- it simply returns the redirect to the browser.

One possible explanation for the behavior you see is that you set the Origin Protocol Policy in CloudFront to "HTTP Only" instead of "HTTPS Only" or "Match Viewer," so the origin is trying to redirect the connection to use HTTPS since it sees the incoming connection (from CloudFront) as HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Another possibility is that you configured CloudFront's Cache Behavior settings to whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin.